# Why use ImageMagick in CMS like MediaWiki instead of simply using browser methods?

Tags: imagemagick, mediawiki, graphicsmagick

Can somebody explain to me why I should possibly use ImageMagick (or the fork GraphicsMagick) in a CMS instead of simply displaying and sizing my images via CSS?

The browser methods cannot fail and are automatically updated on client side, the ImageMagick-binary can fail on the server and I have to maintain it by hand to not become obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick offers lots of image manipulations not available via normal HTML/CSS operations. So for some tasks, your browser just can't do the  modifications.

One very important task is simply file size: if a user uploads a 20MB image you don't want to deliver that to your clients with a 3G mobile connection and let them scale the image down: you want to have your server do that task once and then serve images that are substantially smaller in size.

Comment: Also,  ImageMagick creates png thumbs for SVG files, that still not every web user can see in their browsers

Comment: And [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/1_Wild_Turkey.jpg) is an example of a Wikimedia Commons images that you do not want download in full just to read about [the turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_(bird))

Comment: Serving small images speeds up browsing experience for the reader and cuts down bandwidth costs for the site owner. Also, older browsers have poor resize algorithms which result in ugly-looking images if you let the browser do the resizing. And even for widely supported file formats, there are certain features not all browsers support, such as EXIF rotation in JPEG.